Learning a boolean function using decision tree with small number of queries
I am working on a problem and I am looking to solve the following subproblem : Given a "restrictive" blackbox access to boolean function $\phi$, output a "small-sized" CNF that reasonably approximates $\phi$.
More precisely, suppose $\phi:\{0,1\}^n\to \{0,1\}$ and we can somehow sample from the assignments that make $\phi$ true. Given a parameter $m$, can we find a CNF formula $\hat\phi$ with at most $m$ clauses such that the distance (say the total variation distance or something similar) between $\phi$ and $\hat\phi$ is small (may depend on $m$) and uses small amount of samples?
I was thinking of using some form of a decision tree learning model to do the job, but I can't really see how to do it exactly. Nor can I find any literature on the same.
Any help is appreciated!

This seems relevant (though may be an incomparable requirement wrt learning guarantee): https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~rocco/papers/soda15.html

Related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/22122/755
